# Why are my guest data extensions not available for basic segmentation?

Tags: cdp

I have created guest data extensions using the endpoint : https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/sitecore-cdp-guest-extensions-data-model-for-rest-api.html

After waiting 24 hours for the schema for Batch Segmentation to be updated, i still cant see these data extensions available for Basic Segmentation in the UI.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for adding a guest data extension it specifies that the data extension name must be ext.
https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/sitecore-cdp-guest-extensions-data-model-for-rest-api.html

Therefore the endpoint needs to be:
https://{{apiEndpoint}}/v2/guests/{{guestRef}}/extext

For the endpoint, use `extext`, not `extExt`

- `extext` shows up in both profile and basic segments UI
- `extExt` shows up in profile but not basic segments UI
- ext results in a 404 response

Once the data extension is setup like this, then you can query the field in the segmentation UI or search of the fields in the search bar.

One thing to note is the data model being used here in segmentation is updated every 24 hours, so after you add your new data extension you will need to wait 24 hours until you can see the field available in the UI for segmentation.